# multiprocess not appearing in Python

Tags: python

I have coded the following map reduce example:

```
import collections
import itertools
import multiprocessing


class SimpleMapReduce:

    def __init__(self, map_func, reduce_func, num_workers=None):
        """
        map_func

          Function to map inputs to intermediate data. Takes as
          argument one input value and returns a tuple with the
          key and a value to be reduced.

        reduce_func

          Function to reduce partitioned version of intermediate
          data to final output. Takes as argument a key as
          produced by map_func and a sequence of the values
          associated with that key.

        num_workers

          The number of workers to create in the pool. Defaults
          to the number of CPUs available on the current host.
        """
        self.map_func = map_func
        self.reduce_func = reduce_func
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_workers)

    def partition(self, mapped_values):
        """Organize the mapped values by their key.
        Returns an unsorted sequence of tuples with a key
        and a sequence of values.
        """
        partitioned_data = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for key, value in mapped_values:
            partitioned_data[key].append(value)
        return partitioned_data.items()

    def __call__(self, inputs, chunksize=1):
        """Process the inputs through the map and reduce functions
        given.

        inputs
          An iterable containing the input data to be processed.

        chunksize=1
          The portion of the input data to hand to each worker.
          This can be used to tune performance during the mapping
          phase.
        """
        map_responses = self.pool.map(
            self.map_func,
            inputs,
            chunksize=chunksize,
        )
        partitioned_data = self.partition(
            itertools.chain(*map_responses)
        )
        reduced_values = self.pool.map(
            self.reduce_func,
            partitioned_data,
        )
        return reduced_values
    

import string

def file_to_words(filename):
    """Read a file and return a sequence of
    (word, occurences) values.
    """
    STOP_WORDS = set([
        'a', 'an', 'and', 'are', 'as', 'be', 'by', 'for', 'if',
        'in', 'is', 'it', 'of', 'or', 'py', 'rst', 'that', 'the',
        'to', 'with',
    ])
    TR = str.maketrans({
        p: ' '
        for p in string.punctuation
    })
    
    print("any message")

    print('{} reading {}'.format(
        multiprocessing.current_process().name, filename))
    output = []

    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            # Skip comment lines.
            if line.lstrip().startswith('..'):
                continue
            line = line.translate(TR)  # Strip punctuation
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.lower()
                if word.isalpha() and word not in STOP_WORDS:
                    output.append((word, 1))
    return output


def count_words(item):
    """Convert the partitioned data for a word to a
    tuple containing the word and the number of occurences.
    """
    word, occurences = item
    return (word, sum(occurences))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import operator
    import glob

    input_files = glob.glob('*.py')

    mapper = SimpleMapReduce(file_to_words, count_words)
    word_counts = mapper(input_files)
    word_counts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    word_counts.reverse()

    print('\nTOP 20 WORDS BY FREQUENCY\n')
    top20 = word_counts[:20]
    longest = max(len(word) for word, count in top20)
    for word, count in top20:
        print('{word:<{len}}: {count:5}'.format(
            len=longest + 1,
            word=word,
            count=count)
        )
```

which is taken from: https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/mapreduce.html

However, it seems that the part of the workers is not running. For example, in the original code something like this should appear:

```
ForkPoolWorker-1 reading basics.rst
ForkPoolWorker-2 reading communication.rst
ForkPoolWorker-3 reading index.rst
ForkPoolWorker-4 reading mapreduce.rst
```

I know that my files are different, but I can also see that the def file_to_words(filename) is not reached; I have put a print message and it does not print anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: I ran this code on python 3.8.10 and it printed the following: 
```
any message
ForkPoolWorker-1 reading example.py

TOP 20 WORDS BY FREQUENCY

word        :    21
map         :    12
func        :    11
self        :    11
data        :    10
values      :     8
key         :     8
count       :     7
words       :     7
partitioned :     7
reduce      :     7
import      :     6
line        :     5
return      :     5
pool        :     5
input       :     5
inputs      :     5
def         :     5
counts      :     4
print       :     4
```

Comment: Your num_workers default value is none. While calling the mapper you are also not providing the num_workers. Put a value there and then it should work

Comment: Something like `mapper = SimpleMapReduce(file_to_words, count_words,4)`

Comment: maybe first check `input_files` - if you have less files then it may runs less workers. And when you use `num_workers=None` then number of workers may depends on number of Cores in CPU and on older CPU it may create less workers.

Comment: and files have different size then one worker may read many files before other work start and you may get names `ForkPoolWorker-...` in random order.

Comment: thanks @ManishDash I have changed the num_workers and also change to a directory with like 100 files, and still the ForkPoolWorker does not apppear.